# Abrir formulario externo a BBDDs Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, microsoft-office

Supongamos que tengo una base de datos access Database2.accdb que compilo y convierto a Database2.accde y que además tengo otra Database1.mda que funciona como complemento. Este complemento Database1.mda no está agregado al proyecto VBA como referencia por lo que en modo ejecución de Database2.accde no puedo agregarlo. Lo que necesito entonces es desde Database2.accde en ejecución abrir un formulario de Database1.mda y que se muestre en el "screen" o ventana de Database2.accde. En un botón en un formulario llamo al formulario externo de estas formas y nada, ¿me ayudáis?, gracias y saludos

```
Private Sub btnMostrarFormularioExterno_Click()
    ' Abre la base de datos externa
    Dim frm As Access.Form
    Dim app As Object
    Set app = CreateObject("Access.Application")
    app.OpenCurrentDatabase CurrentProject.Path & "\AA.mda", False

    ' Abre el formulario externo en la base de datos externa
    app.DoCmd.OpenForm "Formulario2", acDialog

    ' Esto lo he agregado y solo me muestra como abierto el Formulario1
    ' que es el principal donde está el botón
    '
    For Each frm In Forms
        MsgBox frm.Name
    Next frm
    
    ' Cierra la instancia de la aplicación Access externa
    app.Quit
    Set app = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: ¿Por qué abres la base en una instancia aparte de Access? ¿Por qué no en la misma instancia y desde ahí controlas todo?

Comment: Hola, en realidad no tengo idea de como hacerlo como dices

Comment: Tengo la misma necesidad y por esta línea ya había pasado app.DoCmd.OpenForm "NombreDelFormulario", acDialog y como a ti no se muestra el formulario. Si a continuación hago visible la instancia se muestra el formulario y la nueva instancia de Access, cosa que yo tampoco quiero. ¿Has llegado a alguna conclusión efectiva pfigueredo? Rafael.

Answer (score 1):

El primer código que proporcionas no funciona porque estás intentando cargar el formulario externo en un control de subformulario. Esto no funcionará porque el complemento no está agregado al proyecto VBA.

El segundo código funciona, pero abre el formulario externo en una ventana independiente. Esto no es lo que quieres, ya que quieres que el formulario externo se muestre en la misma ventana que la base de datos de Access.

Para solucionar este problema, puedes usar el siguiente código:

```
Private Sub btnMostrarFormularioExterno_Click()
    ' Abre la base de datos externa
    Dim app As Object
    Set app = CreateObject("Access.Application")
    app.OpenCurrentDatabase "Ruta\Hacia\BaseDeDatosExterna.mda", False

    ' Abre el formulario externo en la base de datos externa
    app.DoCmd.OpenForm "NombreDelFormulario", acDialog

    ' Cierra la instancia de la aplicación Access externa
    app.Quit
    Set app = Nothing
End Sub
```

Este código funciona porque usa el método DoCmd.OpenForm para abrir el formulario externo en modo de diálogo. Esto significa que el formulario externo se mostrará en la misma ventana que la base de datos de Access.

Comment: Estaré haciendo algo mal, no me va y la BBDDs externa se abre porque veo el .ldb,, edito la pregunta con el código actual